# How can I delete the selected random list of 3 rows, and move the rest of cell values from lower rows to replace the removed above 3 rows?

Tags: python, openpyxl, rows

The first 8 below lines searches for all cell values:

```
departure_removal =  ws_fhr["B6:F30"]
flight_obj = "5H-"

for row in departure_removal:
    for cell in row:
        cell_value = cell.value
        cord = cell.coordinate
        #print(cord, cell_value)
```

Below grabs the rows with flight registration number "5H"  within cell values, and it found 3 rows each flight in its list meaning 3 lists representing 3 rows. But on line `delete_rows()` it deletes randomly others in a different row above and below the targeted 3 rows. Does anyone have a clue how I can go around this?

```
if flight_obj in str(cell_value):
        grab_row = [cell.value for cell in row]
        #print(grab_row)
```

The above grab_row prints the 3 list of rows that i want to delete are these ones, they are random like Row12, Row15 and Row23 as shown ['TC200', 'NBO', '5H-', 'DH8D', '0530']
['TC212', 'HRE-LUN', '5H-', 'BCS3', '1040']
['TC202', 'NBO', '5H-', 'DH8D', '2000']
I want to delete above 3 selected random list of rows

```
        ws_fhr.delete_rows(idx=1, amount=grab_row)
        wb_fhr.save(f"{string_month_year}.xlsx")
```

But on running the code it raises this Error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in 
> start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
> exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  **main**.**dict**)
> File "", line 26, in 
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 729, in delete_rows
> remainder = _gutter(idx, amount, self.max_row)
> File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 900, in _gutter
> gutter = range(max(max_val+1-offset, idx), min(idx+offset, max_val)+1)
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'list'
>
> [Program finished]

Comment: Because you put `amount=len(grab_row)`. Why? You are deleting an amount of rows similar to the size of the current row... `delete_rows` *already* does what you want - it moves the values below the deleted row up

Comment: What do you mean by "random"?

Comment: I tried that ws_fhr.delete_rows(idx=1, amount=grab_row)
And it gave me this error ['TC200', 'NBO', '5H-', 'DH8D', '0530']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 31, in <module>
    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_run/iiec_run.py", line 30, in start
    exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)
  File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
  File "/data/user/0/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/work

Comment: @CharlieClark I have updated the qstn, I meant The above grab_row prints the 3 list of rows that i want to delete are these ones, they are random like Row12, Row15 and Row23 as shown ['TC200', 'NBO', '5H-', 'DH8D', '0530'] ['TC212', 'HRE-LUN', '5H-', 'BCS3', '1040'] ['TC202', 'NBO', '5H-', 'DH8D', '2000'] I want to delete above 3 list of rows, but this line of code doesn't delete them ws_fhr.delete_rows(idx=1, amount=grab_row)

Comment: `amount=grab_row` makes even less sense... Why are you even touching `amount`? It seems to me that you simply want to delete one row every time.

Comment: I wasn't sure abt it also, I had the same doubts, how can I move forward pass that line..I was thinking if I could get the first list and delete it then the next one n the third one..and each time I delete that specific row, the lower values will replace the deleted row..but how can code this..?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I really understand the question correctly, but it sounds like you are hitting one of Python's gotchas when working with mutable structues like lists and dictionaries.

If you are creating a list of rows to delete you must take into account that when you delete the first row, the indexes for the other rows to delete are no longer correct. The best way to avoid this is always to delete rows from the end of the worksheet first.

The canonical example for what I think you're observing is

```py
l = list(range(10))
for i in l:
    print(i)
    l.pop(i)
```

This shows you the effect of removing items from a list as you loop over it and the resulting `IndexError`.

Comment: Unfortunately it couldn't work,  I even tried, tried a=Len(grab_row) for j in range(1, a+1): ws_fhr.cell(row=j, column=3).value = None but it ends up saying AttributeError: "MergedCell object attribute value is read-only

Comment: That's completely unrelated to deleting rows but also self-explanatory.

Comment: Finally this delete_rows  worked out with the idx passing in the cell.row otherwise gr8 thanx in advance to those who contributed to get passed this hiccup!